# htaccess redirect to subdomain not as required

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a problem. 
The name of my homepage is as example "blabla.org". But the Home Site is on "home.blabla.org". I have a htaccess, which redirects me to "home.blabla.org" if i go to "blabla.org" But if i want to go to "blabla.org/test.html" ist redirects me to "home.blabla.orgtest.html"

How can I fix that?

Here my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blabla\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://home.blabla.org$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to redirect only the homepage :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blabla\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://home.blabla.org [R=301, L]
```

Edit : to redirect homepage of every subdomain, you just have to do the same and exclude only home.blabla.org :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^home\.blabla\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://home.blabla.org [R=301, L]
```

Comment: this doesnt work. If i write "blabl.org/test.html" it redirects me to "home.blabla.orgtest.html" but it should go to "blabl.org/test.html"

Comment: Oh, you just want to redirect your homepage to home.blabla.org, anything else goes to blabla.org ? Is that correct ?

Comment: If i go to "blabla.org" it should redirect to "home.blabla.org" Everything else should not redirect. "blabla.org/test.html" should go to blabla.org/test.html"

Comment: I have updated my post now that I have understood what you need :)

Comment: Everything works like I want it. But now I found an other problem with this. Not sure if possible to fix it.
When i now write "asdasd.blabla.org" it shows me the File Content of my /var/www file. Thats not so good. 
When I type "asdasd.blabla.org" it should redirect to "home.blabla.org". Is this posible?

Comment: Answer updated. It should now redirect every homepage to home.blabla.org except home.blabla.org to avoid redirection loop. Untested however.